# create block inside transactional emails to solve {{if}} problem

Tags: blocks, transactional-mail, if

I'm new to magento. The problem that I have is that I want to modify the template of a transactional email.

It's basically a return that I want the customer to receive a different email if the return is "rejected" or "approved".

I tried to modify the code with an if but realize that it doesn't let me compare strings. Only it says if the variable is TRUE or FALSE

`{{if order.delivery_time=="10"}}`    is not possible.

I can't touch the code because it has a comment that says that if the Magento version gets updated, the file will be completely overwritten.

So, I thought about creating a block, which I don't have a clear understanding on how to do it.

I think it is something like this...

`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="this_block" template="cms/content.phtml"}}`

But my question is.... What should I write in the template section? and what about the block id section?

I'm sorry but I'm a begginer. 
If you give me a hint, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

> {{block type="cms/block" block_id="this_block"
>   template="cms/content.phtml"}}

Where **type** is the required attribute. **cms/block**, cms reffers to **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block** and **block** reffers to Block class. So for **cms/block**, actual class is **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block**. **template** is the output phtml template location. block_id reffers to, you can access this value inside block class or corresponding phtml template class using

```
$this->getBlockId()
```

If you open following class:

> app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php

Check following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Prepare Content HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
    $html = '';
    if ($blockId) {
        $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($blockId);
        if ($block->getIsActive()) {
            /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
            $this->addModelTags($block);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

**$blockId = $this->getBlockId();** take the block id and loaded cms block.

Now open following the corresponding template:
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/content.phtml**

Comment: THANK very much! I don't have my PC here, but I'll try tomorrow as soon as I can. As I said, I'm very new to the Magento world. Where should I write the code? Let's say that I want to add an IF statement, where should I put it? What file? what part?   THANKS again!!!

Comment: I'm using Magento 1.9 I forgot to clarify